How can i calculate this integral $\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2a-iwx}\,dx$
How can i calculate this integral? $$\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(-x^2/2a)-iwx}\,dx$$
I tried using the software symbolab but it didn't appear a solution

this is the Fourier Transform of a Gaussian function

Strictly speaking wouldn't you have to consider a rectangular contour of height $aw$ in the imaginary axis in order to relate $\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{a}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{- \frac{1}{2a} [(x+iaw)^2 + a^2 w^2]} dx$ to $\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{a}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{- \frac{1}{2a} [x^2 + a^2 w^2]} dx$? This has probably already been done.
